# Help identifying package lead

Tags: switches, packages

I have this surface mount switch and noticed that the lead type is slightly different than other similar switch types. I know that it's not a J-Lead or Gull Wing as J-Leads typically protrude from the surface of the package.

Would it simply be called an SMD terminal, tab, pad, etc? Or would there be a proper name to this? Would anyone know if there's specific terminology for this lead?

I'm not designing anything, I'm simply curious about the terminology.

[Here's](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electronic%20Components/EVQQ3.pdf) the datasheet of the device in question.

[image]

When I compare the joystick leads to that of this [JEDEC standard](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/j-lead?destination=node/15262), the pins do not form into a J-shaped configuration with the portion of the lead in contact with the printed wiring board.

Comment: Why the down vote? I feel this is a legitimate questions towards design. Please see my edit for more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from below, the leads for J-lead type packages tend to stick out from the side of the package and wrap around underneath. This is pretty much what the leads are doing on the SMD switch you show except on the switch they wrap in the opposite direction - start underneath and pull up around the sides.

In which case I'd still be happy calling it a J-lead package.

[image: J-Lead package]

Comment: I would too call this "J-lead".  At the same time, this classification is not of great practical importance, because a custom PCB footprint would have to be created for that exotic button.  Fortunately, the datasheet provides a drawing for the footprint.  (Neat button/joystick, by the way.)